# JSON transformation via Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have an input JSON below which I want to transform it into another JSON structure:

Input JSON

```
{
    data={
       
            schema=81Ze2hDYGKOQYW02LVtUMQ,
            payload={
                        value__c=500,
                        reference__c=00001503PM,
                        CreatedById=0051x000003SQ9eAAG,
                        originalReference__c=882595596510490G,
                        currency__c=SEK,
                        CreatedDate=2020-09-10T15:16:57.175Z,
                        merchantAccount__c=Hastens_eCom_Test
                    },
            event={replayId=18188}
        },
            channel=/event/Capturepayment__e
}
```

and I want to transform it into the format below.

Output JSON

```
   {
      "originalReference": "882595596510490G",
      "modificationAmount": {
        "value": 500,
        "currency": "SEK"
      },
      "reference": "00001503PM",
      "merchantAccount": "Hastens_eCom_Test"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input payload doesn't seem to be a valid JSON.

Using the input payload adjusted to be a valid JSON:

```
{
   "data":{
      "schema":"81Ze2hDYGKOQYW02LVtUMQ",
      "payload":{
         "value__c":500,
         "reference__c":"00001503PM",
         "CreatedById":"0051x000003SQ9eAAG",
         "originalReference__c":"882595596510490G",
         "currency__c":"SEK",
         "CreatedDate":"2020-09-10T15:16:57.175Z",
         "merchantAccount__c":"Hastens_eCom_Test"
      },
      "event":{
         "replayId":"18188"
      }
   },
   "channel":"/event/Capturepayment__e"
}
```

the following dataweave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  originalReference: payload.data.payload.originalReference__c,
  modificationAmount: {
    value: payload.data.payload.value__c,
    currency: payload.data.payload.currency__c,
  },
  reference: payload.data.payload.reference__c,
  merchantAccount: payload.data.payload.merchantAccount__c
}
```

will result in the expected output:

```
{
  "originalReference": "882595596510490G",
  "modificationAmount": {
    "value": 500,
    "currency": "SEK"
  },
  "reference": "00001503PM",
  "merchantAccount": "Hastens_eCom_Test"
}
```

Comment: The input is probable the output of the Salesforce connector as Java maps. Your script should work the same for either as long as the structure and data types are the same.

Comment: @aled you are correct! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The below dwl will produce the expected output

```
%dw 2.3
output application/json
---
{
  originalReference: payload.data.payload.originalReference__c,
  modificationAmount: {
    value: payload.data.payload.value__c,
    currency: payload.data.payload.currency__c,
  },
  reference: payload.data.payload.reference__c,
  merchantAccount: payload.data.payload.merchantAccount__c
}
```